# Angular.js "Controller As" on templateUrl/template ng-click/blur/focus events not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax, angularjs-controller

I know this has to be a simple thing I'm overlooking, but google is not being my friend right now.

When using the ["controllerAs"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example) syntax, for some reason if I use it for an element within a template, the clicks do not register. 
Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qldIu3nHODQyaJtoW0Zi)

## html

```
<section ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <p>Hello {{main.name}}!</p>
    <div class='button' ng-click="main.openDoor()">You can click this and it will alert!</div>

    <dude class='button'></dude>
</section>
```

## js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('dude', function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E"
    , scope: {}
    , controller : 'main'
    , controllerAs: 'main'

// vv confusion

    , template: '<div ng-click="main.openDoor()">This is a different thing but clicking it does nothing even though i literall copy pasted this element!</div>'

// ^^confusion

    , transclude : true
  }
}).controller("MainCtrl", function(){
  this.name = "true";
  this.openDoor = function(){     // <==== confusion.
    alert(Object.keys(this));
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't set the directive's controller correctly, it should be:

`controller : 'MainCtrl'`

rather than `main`. The `controller` property assigns the actual controller, while `controllerAs` gives an alias to the controller object, which is edited using `this` in a controller.

[Docs reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k2pqQxtoRU0zK225S4Rw?p=preview).